# Amazon Cognito - Multilingual email messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm developing a multilingual application - currently the application works with 3 different languages. Is there a way to handle multilingual email verification in Amazon Cognito?

Thanks,
Lucas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is the `CustomMessage` lambda trigger [(docs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html).

In this lambda you receive `request.userAttributes` which includes all the user attributes for the recipient; including locale, if you set it.

You can use this information to select from your email templates in various languages, and return the desired e-mail as `response.emailSubject` and `response.emailMessage`.

From what I can see in the service documentation, there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this automatically without taking control and using this lambda trigger.

Comment: n.b. feel free to comment if you want further information on using this lambda.

Comment: how do you add locale to `request.userAttributes` ?